# Angular 2: How to tell SystemJS to use a bundle?

Tags: javascript, angular, bundle, systemjs

I have an Angular 2 RC7 app where I use SystemJS to load JavaScript files.

This is my current configuration for SystemJS:

```
(function (global) {

System.config({

    defaultExtension: 'js',
    defaultJSExtensions: true,

    paths: {
        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },

    // Let the system loader know where to look for things
    map: {

        // Our app is within the app folder
        app: 'app',

        // Angular bundles
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

        // Other libraries
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
        'ng2-translate': 'node_modules/ng2-translate'

    },

    // Tell the system loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
        app: { main: './main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        rxjs: { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'ng2-translate': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
    }

});

})(this);
```

Now I have created a bundle called `app.bundle.min.js` that contains all my app logic, and a `dependencies.bundle.min.js` that contains dependencies used.

How do I tell SystemJS to use these files instead of importing the files individually?

I have tried replacing this:

```
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ 
    console.error(err); 
  });
</script>
```

with:

```
<script src="production/dependencies.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="production/app.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

in my index.html, but that's not working. As long as I keep the `System.import...` script block inside index.html, the app loads but using individual files instead of bundles.

I also tried changing this:

```
map: {

    // Our app is within the app folder
    app: 'production/app.bundle.min.js',
```

but that did not work either.

This is how the bundles are generated using Gulp:

```
gulp.task('inline-templates', function () {

return gulp.src('app/**/*.ts')
.pipe(inlineNg2Template({
    UseRelativePaths: true, 
    indent: 0,
    removeLineBreaks: true
}))
.pipe(tsc({
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
 }))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

});

gulp.task('bundle-app', ['inline-templates'], function() {

var builder = new systemjsBuilder('', 'app/configs/systemjs.config.js');

return builder
    .bundle('dist/**/* - [@angular/**/*.js] - [rxjs/**/*.js]', 'production/app.bundle.min.js', { 
        minify: true,
        mangle: true
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Build complete');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Build error');
        console.log(err);
    });

});

gulp.task('bundle-dependencies', ['inline-templates'], function() {

var builder = new systemjsBuilder('', 'app/configs/systemjs.config.js');

return builder
    .bundle('dist/**/*.js - [dist/**/*.js]', 'production/dependencies.bundle.min.js', { 
        minify: true,
        mangle: true
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Build complete');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Build error');
        console.log(err);
    });

});

gulp.task('production', ['bundle-app', 'bundle-dependencies'], function(){});
```

I suspect I have to somehow change mappings inside my SystemJS configuration to point towards the bundles? How do I do this?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing exactly how bundles are generated

Comment: I have added the gulp task to my question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to the `map` and `packages` in your SystemJS config,

```
System.import('app')
```

translates into the request for the file `app/main.js`.  However, if you look into generated app bundle, you see that this module is actually registered as

```
System.registerDynamic("dist/main.js" ...
```

because the bundle was generated from `.js` files in the `dist` folder.

This mismatch is the reason why your modules are not loaded from the script bundle.

One possible solution is to always keep `.ts` and `.js` files in separate folders - `.ts` in `app`, `.js` in `dist`. That way, systemjs will need to know only about `dist`: the only part of systemjs.config.js that needs to change is `app` mapping:

```
// Let the system loader know where to look for things
map: {

    // Our app is compiled to js files in the dist folder
    app: 'dist',
```

To check that it works, I started from [angular quickstart example](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) and added `gulpfile.js` with these tasks:

1. compile typescript into `dist` using [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript) plugin.

   ```
   var gulp = require('gulp');
   var typescript = require('typescript');
   var tsc = require('gulp-typescript');

   var systemjsBuilder = require('systemjs-builder');

   gulp.task('tsc', function () {

     return gulp.src(['app/**/*.ts', 'typings/index.d.ts'])
       .pipe(tsc({
         "target": "es5",
         "module": "commonjs",
         "moduleResolution": "node",
         "sourceMap": true,
         "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
         "experimentalDecorators": true,
         "removeComments": true,
         "noImplicitAny": false,
         "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
       }))
       .js.pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
   });
   ```
2. copy systemjs config file into `dist` folder, so that is will be bundled together with the app code and will be available in production (it's needed because you are using `bundle` and not `buildStatic`)

   ```
   gulp.task('bundle-config', function() {
     return gulp.src('app/configs/systemjs.config.js')
       .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/configs'));
   });
   ```
3. generate bundles with systemjs builder:

   ```
   gulp.task('bundle-app', ['bundle-config', 'tsc'], function() {

     var builder = new systemjsBuilder('', 'app/configs/systemjs.config.js');
     return builder
         .bundle('[dist/**/*]', 'production/app.bundle.min.js', {
             minify: true,
             mangle: true
         })
         .then(function() {
             console.log('Build complete');
         })
         .catch(function(err) {
             console.log('Build error');
             console.log(err);
         });

   });

   gulp.task('bundle-dependencies', ['bundle-config', 'tsc'], function() {

     var builder = new systemjsBuilder('', 'app/configs/systemjs.config.js');
     return builder
         .bundle('dist/**/* - [dist/**/*.js]', 'production/dependencies.bundle.min.js', {
             minify: true,
             mangle: true
         })
         .then(function() {
             console.log('Build complete');
         })
         .catch(function(err) {
             console.log('Build error');
             console.log(err);
         });

     });

   gulp.task('production', ['bundle-app', 'bundle-dependencies'], function(){});
   ```

Note that it uses `[dist/**/*]` syntax for generating app bundle without any dependencies - the one in your gulpfile.js is different and generates much bigger bundle which includes some dependencies - I don't know if it's intentional or not.

Then, I created `index-production.html` with these changes from `index.html`:

1. remove `<script>` tag for `systemjs.config.js` - we import it from the bundle
2. add `<script>` tags for bundles in `<head>`

   ```
   <script src="production/dependencies.bundle.min.js"></script>
   <script src="production/app.bundle.min.js"></script>
   ```
3. add inline `<script>` that imports config and app module:

   ```
   <script>
     System.import('dist/configs/systemjs.config.js').then(function() {
       System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
     });
   </script>
   ```

importing 'app' module is necessary because bundles generated with `bundle` do not import anything and don't run any code - they are only making all the modules available for import later, unlike 'sfx' bundles generated with `buildStatic`.

Also, this script block needs to be in the `<body>` after `<my-app>` element, otherwise `app` will start too early when the `<my-app>` element is not created yet (alternatively, `import('app')` can be called on 'document ready' event).

You can find complete example on github: https://github.com/fictitious/test-systemjs-angular-gulp

Comment: Amazing reply. Thank you very much! Your solution worked like a charm.

Comment: @artem is it possible with this solution to debug the ts files in browser?

Comment: @Yvan yes, you need to install and configure gulp-sourcemaps. I updated example repo.

Comment: I have started and will award you (in 24 hours) a 100 bounty for the incredible help in this answer!